# Automatically minimize the VB.Net 2012 IDE while debugging..?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to automatically minimize the VB.Net 2012 IDE when debugging is started..? I looked through Tools > Options > Debugging > General but did not see a setting for it. I'm not sure if it can be done in code, perhaps with #IF compiler directives, which would be omitted in the compiled release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Visual Commander and the [Minimize Visual Studio on Debugging](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#minimize_vs_on_debug) extension for it.